modifying systemd tmp.mount parameters
In RHEL 7 and later as well as other Linux distributions, systemctl enable tmp.mount makes the /tmp folder a tmpfs (a temporary file system).
In RHEL 8.10 for example, by default those parameters are I think
# mount | grep tmp

tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,seclabel)

In addition on my particular server...
# df -h

Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                378G  120K  378G   1% /tmp

What is the correct or preferred way to alter these mount options, and size, of /tmp ?
I want to see Avail as 10gb, and have nodev,nosuid,noexec also present as mount options.
In addition to systemctl enable tmp.mount is putting this entry in /etc/fstab good or bad practice to achieve this given the systemd association with tmp.mount ?  Is there a better way?
tmpfs    /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec,size=10G    0 0


the other question frowns upon putting the systemd tmp.mount in /etc/fstab;  I want to know specifically how you can modify the mount parameters of what is a systemd mounting method - is there a systemd_tmp.mount.conf  ?

The answer to the other question says “In both setups, /etc/fstab is still the recommended way of customising /tmp mounts, e.g. to change their size”.
